# Grid-a-licious plugin flickers on jQuery Mobile page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

**My goal :**

Use jQuery plugin `grid-a-licious` to display a *pinterest-like* grid, inside a jQuery Mobile page. When the page loads, images must be arranged in a grid.

**The (failed) outcome :**

The code I came up with is illustrated here : http://jsfiddle.net/hxNDE/6/

Basically, I use the `pageshow` JQM event to activate Grid-a-licious. It works, BUT, there is a major flickering due to page transition :

```
$('#page-2').on('pageshow', function () {
    $("#grid").gridalicious({
        gutter: 1,
        width: 100
    });
});
```

When I use `pagebeforeshow` event instead, *it does not work at all*, because Grid-a-licious cannot detect screen width and decide how many columns to build :

```
$('#page-2').on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    ...same...
});
```

**Current workaround:**
I have disabled all JQM transition animations, so there is no visible flickering when the images are arranged in a grid.

**I would like to find a solution where I can use JQM transition AND Grid-a-licious without the flickering.**

- By finding a way in JQM
- or, by modifying Grid-a-licious plugin, which is pretty short, to overcome this situation

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue, and pulled a fix to Grid-A-Licious git repository :

https://github.com/suprb/Grid-A-Licious/pull/22

Basically, the width was wrongly calculated when css `display` was hidden or, well, not in its normal state

```
var swappedStyle = this.box.css('display');
this.box.css('display', 'block');
width = this.box.width(); // Previously, only this line
this.box.css('display', swappedStyle);
```

**Notes :**

- This does not enables jQuery Mobile transitions, but merely gets Gris-A-Licious usable with JQM
- Also included a fix for iOS devices which trigger a lot of resize event, hence making Gridalicious flicker and scroll to top